# How-To: Multiple Column Sort in AngularJS, while maintaining 'Always on Top' record(s)?

Tags: angularjs, sorting

I have a simple table that I'm doing sorting on, and I'd like to be able to sort by one of two columns (date or 'has attachment'), but keep specific records at the top of the table (records that are 'pinned') and just sort the rows AFTER that.

**Html Code**

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 50px" class="centered">
                <div class="icon-refresh clickable" ng-click="loadNotes()"></div>
            </th>
            <th class="clickable colored_text" style="width: 50px"  ng-click="sort('LastModified')">Last Modified</th>
            <th class="clickable colored_text" style="width: 50px"  ng-click="sort('HasAttachment')">Attachment</th>
            <th>Note</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr ng-show="notesLoaded == true && notes.length == 0">
        <td colspan="3">No notes found.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="note in notes | filter: myFilterNotes | orderBy: noteSortOrder: noteSortDirection | startAt: (currentPage-1)*pageSize | limitTo :pageSize " ng-class="{'pinned': note.Pinned}">
        <td class="span1"><button class="btn btn-inverse" ng-click="editNote(note.Id)" ng-show="(note.CreatedBy == history.currentUserId && note.TypeId === 0) || (history.canEditNotes && note.TypeId === 0)">Edit</button></td>
        <td>{{note.LastModified | date:'MM/dd/yyyy h:mm a'}}</td>
        <td  class="centered">
            <span ng-if="note.HasAttachment">
                <a href ng-click="downloadAttachment(note)"><i class="icon-paper-clip icon-1point5x" title="{{note.NoteFileName}}"></i></a>
            </span>
        </td>
        <td class="forceWordWrap">
            <div class="span11">
                <span ng-show="note.TypeId === 1">(Lead Note) </span>
                <span ng-if="note.IsValidHtml" ng-bind-html="note.Note"></span>
                <span ng-if="!note.IsValidHtml" ng-repeat="line in (note.Note | newlines) track by $index">
                    {{line}}<br/>
                </span>
                <span style="color: #bbb; font-size: 85%; font-weight: normal">
                    <p style="margin: 0;">-- created by {{(note.CreatedByName.length > 0) ? note.CreatedByName : "Unknown"}} on {{::note.CreatedDate | date:'MM/dd/yyyy h:mm a' }}</p>
                    <span ng-show="note.LastModifiedBy.length > 0">
                        <p style="margin: 0;">-- last modified by {{::note.LastModifiedBy}}</p>
                    </span>
                </span>
            </div>
            <span class="span1" ng-show="note.Pinned" style="color: rgb(255, 0, 0);">
                <i class="icon-pushpin icon-1point5x"></i>
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**The Angular Sort method**

```
    $scope.noteSortDirection = true;
    $scope.noteSortOrder = ["Pinned", "HasAttachment"];
    $scope.sort = function (column) {
        $scope.noteSortDirection = !$scope.noteSortDirection;

        var sortColumnWithDirection = $scope.noteSortDirection !== true
                                 ? "-" + column
                                 : column;

        var newSortOrder = ["Pinned", sortColumnWithDirection];

        $scope.noteSortOrder = newSortOrder;
    };
```

The initial multi column sort is working fine, but when I click on either of the headers, it sorts the 'pinned' stuff in some wonky ways. (screenshots below)

---

This is working great!
[image: Initial Sort]

---

This, not so much. It's like it does the sort exactly how I want, and then reverses the entire thing! (grr)
[image: After Clicking a Sort Header]

---

Ideally, this is what I want!
[image: What I want]

Comment: tr ng-repeat="note in filteredNotes"-- Put all your magic logic to javascript.

Comment: I already am. The sort method I put above is what I'm using to do the sort. I just need to know how to tweak it to do what I'm asking it to do.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. I removed the sort order from the ng-repeat:

```
<tr ng-repeat="note in notes | filter: myFilterNotes | orderBy: noteSortOrder: true | startAt: (currentPage-1)*pageSize | limitTo :pageSize " ng-class="{'pinned': note.Pinned}">
```

and updated the custom sort method to deal with the sort order at the right time:

```
        $scope.sort = function (column) {
            var sortDir = $scope.noteSortDirection;
            var revSortDir = !sortDir;

            var sortColumnWithDirection = revSortDir !== true
                                              ? "-" + column
                                              : column;

            var newSortOrder = ["Pinned", sortColumnWithDirection];

            $scope.noteSortDirection = !$scope.noteSortDirection;

            $scope.noteSortOrder = newSortOrder;
        };
```